# Configuring ethernet network

Tags: 10.10, networking, configuration

I've got a wired network connection and if I'm using network manager (hereafter "NM") everything works fine except for the hardware address (it doesn't change). I'm thinking of using `/etc/network/interfaces`. So, I added some code and it looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address #corresponding value
netmask #corresponding value
gateway #corresponding value
hwaddress #corresponding value
```

After restarting networking I get the following message:

```
*Reconfiguring network interfaces...
#here some help code appears
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

The default interface that works with NM is eth0. Please advise on how to handle the problem.

Comment: Assuming the interface you want to manage using the `interfaces` file is `eth0`, why is it `eth1` in the file?

Comment: I'm setting a different hw address, but at other location (it's a laptop) I'll need the "native" one.

Comment: ethernet is pretty easy to use without NM, if you want to deal with /etc/hosts and /etc/conf.d/net.eth0 directly... (assuming Ubuntu uses those, not sure)

Comment: @mathepic, Neither /etc/conf.d nor /etc/conf.d/net.eth0 are there.

Comment: @den-javamaniac - ahh, my apologies. I guess Ubuntu doesn't use SysV Init Scripts.

Comment: I'd suggest you try entering eth0 anyway. See if it solves any of the issues you're trying to solve using `interfaces`.

Comment: Aren't eth0 and eth1 hardware (not software configuration) anyway? So eth1 probably shouldn't be used for this type of thing.

Comment: @mathepic, looks like that. I should use only eth0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eth0 or eth1 is the logical name given to your network card by Linux (I dont know exactly which component handles the naming but i guess its the kernel). you can only use eth0 or eth1 if its the logical name given to your card and not otherwise.

Coming to your original problem i.e using different hardware address at different locations, this is doable by defining logical name mapping in `/etc/network/interfaces` file but you will have to connect manually to network using `ifup` command eachtime.

To do this open your `/etc/network/interfaces` file and replace its contents with following

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

mapping eth0
      script /home/<username>/net.sh
      map eth0 eth0-home
      map eth0 eth0-work

iface eth0-home inet static
      address #ip address for home
      netmask #subnet mask for home
      hwaddress ether #MAC address for home

iface eth0-work inet static
      address #ipaddress for work
      netmask #netmask for work
      hwaddress ether #MAC address for work
```

set the ip address, netmask and hwaddress for eth0-home and eth0-work to your liking. Also replace the **<username>** in fourth line of the script with your user name. Now save and close the interfaces file.

Now create a file /home/<username>/net.sh with the following contents

```
#!/bin/sh
echo eth0
```

save and close the net.sh file.

You are all set now. You can use command `sudo ifup eth0=eth0-home` to start network with eth0-home settings and `sudo ifup eth0=eth0-work` to start with eth0-work settings.

Also please note that the mapping section in interfaces file and the script file that we created in your users home directory are actually needed when the interface is configured to connect automatically. But we need to provide them for things to work. So the contents of the script file and the contents of mapping section are just sort of place holders. If you are interested in connecting automatically you will need to modify these two. For further discussion of the two you can see man page for interfaces(5) or visit the following link http://addisu.taddese.com/blog/mapping-in-linux-network-interfaces/

Answer (score 1):

You must decide if you want to use NM or the "hardcoded" config in the `interfaces` file. As far as I experienced it's not a good idea to mix them, you will have problems. You may want to drop using NM, ok. However names like `eth0` and `eth1` are assigned to ethernet NICs, so if you use `eth1`, I would think you have two NICs in your machine. Yes, it's possible that you have only `eth1` and not `eth0` (you can even rename NICs) but I don't see the point here. Please issue command `/sbin/ifconfig -a` in terminal and use the eth name what you can see there. If you see only `eth1` and not `eth0` it's ok to use too, that's possible: udev rules names interfaces according the HW address ("MAC address") to be sure, that your interfaces won't be renumbered if you change the PCI card positions and similar things. I had the experience, that replacing a card with another one caused I have only `eth1` (and no `eth0` at all) since udev remembers about the old card's HW address so name `eth0` is reserved for that purpose, thus I had `eth1` as the new NIC. I am not sure you mean about this when you want to use `eth1` but it's nice to mention (btw udev stores assignment(s) here: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`).